# Comparing None values

Tags: python, nonetype

In my code there's a variable `foo` that receives the value from a called function. Because of the parameters passed to this function it returns `None`.

When i execute an `if` comparing the variable `foo` with the `None` value it returns `False`. But if i sign `type(None)` to a `bar` variable and execute the same `if`it returns `True`.

Why?

TL;DR

```
foo = function()
type(foo)
>> <class 'NoneType'>

if foo == None
>> False

bar = None
if foo == bar 
>> False

bar = type(None)
if foo == bar
>> True
```

Why?

Comment: with `def function(): return None` I get True for `foo = function(); print(foo == None)` and also True for bar = None; `print(foo == bar)`

Comment: The posted code isn't valid python, so presumably there's additional relevant code that got edited out. From the looks of what's left, somewhere there's a `foo=type(foo)` or something similar.

Answer (score 0):

> The None object denotes the lack of a value. For the purposes of these operators, the lack of a value indicates that the remainder of the expression also lacks a value and should not be evaluated.

https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0505/